# capture compiling error using python subprocess

Tags: python, c++, subprocess, g++

Using Python to script running GoogleTest with `subprocess`.

My code looks like

```
import subprocess
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename="gtest.log",level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s:%(levelname)s:%(message)s')

output = subprocess.check_output("g++ test.cpp -lgtest -lgtest_main -lpthread -I <some header file path>",shell = True)

logging.info(output.decode("utf-8"))
```

The log file only contains the executable output after compiling is a success. Sometimes, there are missing header files and the compiler will throw an error, for example:

`fatal error: profile.h: No such file or directory`

However, this will not be captured in the log.

My understanding is, since the compilation failed, there is never an `output` variable created. `subprocess` just executed the command and goes to the next when the previous is finished. Python cannot catch that error generated via g++.

Am I thinking it correctly? and if I want to capture the g++ compiling error into the log, what should I do?

Comment: `g++` prints errors to `stderr`, so you need to capture that as well as `stdout`.  Add `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT` to your call to capture it as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to the comment via @Miles Budnek:

`g++` prints errors to `stderr`, so you need to capture that as well as `stdout`. Add `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT` to your call to capture it as well.